# Synchronizing two ppl task on Windows 8 metro app

Tags: c++, visual-c++, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-async

This is metro camera app from msdn. This code is to show preview from the camera.here list of camera will be displayed in the combo box.user can select the camera to see the preview of the selected camera,but when i change the camera it first release the resource and than start the preview of the selected camera.since release process is asynchronous process and it runs in the background, so before releasing, it starts the preview of selected camera and in the mean time release delete the "m_MediaCaptureMgr" pointer and program crashes.

In Win 32 I can use waitforSingle object to synchronize it.I wanted to know how best I can synchronize in WinRT and ppl task.

```
void CameraApp::MainPage::cmbCameraSelector_SelectionChanged(Platform::Object^ sender,  Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SelectionChangedEventArgs^ e)
{
if(m_DeviceVector.size() > 0)
{
    m_CaptureInitSettings->VideoDeviceId = m_DeviceVector[cmbCameraSelector->SelectedIndex]->Id;
    InitMediaCapture();
}
}

void CameraApp::MainPage::InitMediaCapture()
{
ReleaseMediaCapture();

//Sleep(3000);
auto _this = this;
m_MediaCaptureMgr = ref new MediaCapture();

task<void> stratPreview(m_MediaCaptureMgr->InitializeAsync(m_CaptureInitSettings));
stratPreview.then([_this]
{
    _this->previewElement->Source = _this->m_MediaCaptureMgr;
    task<void> startPrev(_this->m_MediaCaptureMgr->StartPreviewAsync());
    startPrev.then([=]
    {

        return _this->GetCameraSettings();
    });     
});

}    
void CameraApp::MainPage::ReleaseMediaCapture()
{
if (m_MediaCaptureMgr )
{
    auto prevOp = m_MediaCaptureMgr->StopPreviewAsync();
    task<void> releaseMediaCapture(m_MediaCaptureMgr->StopPreviewAsync());
    releaseMediaCapture.then([=]
    {
        m_MediaCaptureMgr = nullptr;
        bRelease = false;
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In WinRT you can use [concurrency::event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492846) class. The method [event::wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492803) should be a good replacement for [WaitforSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)